# Firebase security rules syntax with arrays/list property

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Within a Firebase Firestore collection with path 'organizations' each document contains a list of string userID's of users who can update or delete that document.

```
export interface Organization{
  name?: string,
  owners: string[]
}
```

I would like to create a Firebase security rule that ensures that only a logged in user with a uid that is in this list can edit or delete the object. Unsure of the appropriate syntax.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /organizations/{organization} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow create: if request.auth != null;

      /// What should be the syntax here?
      allow update, delete: if request.auth != null && (request.auth.uid in resource.data.owners); // <--------- What should be the syntax for this line?

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, answering my own question here in case it's useful for anyone else.

It looks like the 'in' syntax above actually works even-though it was a complete guess and I wasn't able to find any documentation for it in the firebase security roles documentation.

Final code:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /organizations/{organization} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
      allow update, delete: if (request.auth != null) && (request.auth.uid in resource.data.owners); 
    }
```

Comment: Why do you add `request.auth.uid in resource.data.owners`? It already seems to pass the `request.auth != null` condition, right?

Comment: Got to make sure that the user has edit permissions on that specific document! :-)

Comment: Than you should use `&&` instead of `||`. Now any user can edit :o

Comment: Like @ThomasvanBroekhoven said. But it seems like it fixed already. Otherwise you can do this programmically in your programming language, to ensure you about the correct rules. Best of luck!